# How does open stack assign ip to virtual machines?

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, openstack

I want to know how does the openstack assign ip to virtual machines ? and how to find out port and ips used by the VM. Is it possible for us to find out the IP and ports being used by an application running inside the VM ?

Answer (score 0):

To assign an IP to your VM you can use this command:

```
openstack floating ip create public
```

To associate your VM and the IP use the command below:

```
openstack server add floating ip your-vm-name your-ip-number
```

To list all the ports used by applications, ssh to your instance and run:

```
sudo lsof -i
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the VM name
do the following:
On controller run
*nova interface-list VM-NAME*

It will give you port-id, IP-address and mac address of VM interface.

You can login to VM and run

*netstat -tlnp* to see which IP and ports being used by applications running inside the VM.

As to how a VM gets IP, it depends on your deployment. On a basic openstack deployment when you create a network and create a subnet under that network, you will see on the network node a dhcp namespace getting created. (do *ip netns* on network node). The namespace name would be  qdhcp-network-id. The dnsmasq process running inside the dhcp namespace allots IPs to VM. This is just one of the many ways in which VM gets IP.

Answer (score -3):

This particular [End User page](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/manage_ip_addresses.html) of the official documentation could be a good start:

> "Each instance can have a private, or fixed, IP address and a public, or floating, one.
> Private IP addresses are used for communication between instances, and public ones are used for communication with the outside world.
>
> When you launch an instance, it is automatically assigned a private IP address that stays the same until you explicitly terminate the instance. Rebooting an instance has no effect on the private IP address.
>
> A pool of floating IPs, configured by the cloud operator, is available in OpenStack Compute.
>
> You can allocate a certain number of these to a project: The maximum number of floating IP addresses per project is defined by the quota.
>
> You can add a floating IP address from this set to an instance of the project. Floating IP addresses can be dynamically disassociated and associated with other instances of the same project at any time.
> Before you can assign a floating IP address to an instance, you first must allocate floating IPs to a project. After floating IP addresses have been allocated to the current project, you can assign them to running instances.
>
> You can assign a floating IP address to one instance at a time."

There are of course deeper layers to look at in [this section of the Admin Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content/section_networking-options.html)

Regarding how to find out about ports and IPs, you have two options: command line interface or API. 
For example, if you are using Neutron* and want to find out the IPs or networks in use with the [API](http://api.openstack.org/api-ref-networking.html#networks):

```
 GET v2.0/networks
```

- And using the [CLI](http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content/basic_workflow_with_nova.html):

> ```
> $ neutron net-list
> ```

You can use similar commands for ports and subnets, however I haven't personally tested if you can get information about the application running in the VM this way.

*Check out which OpenStack release you're running.  If it's an old one, chances are it's using the Compute node (Nova) for networking.

Comment: Your answer is not what user wanted. Please look again to question and update your answer.